# Specify default number of articles to fetch

Tags: gnus

When selecting a newsgroup to read, `gnus` prompts for the number of articles to fetch. The value it shows is the number of articles in the group.

I recall that there was a way to specify a default value, such that `gnus` would prompt to load only the most recent, say, 500 articles.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the group parameter `large-newsgroup-initial` to 500 for "All" (default is nil), and you should get what you want - a prompt if there are more than `gnus-large-newsgroup` unread articles, where the prompt defaults to 500 (instead of the number of unread articles).

Answer (score 1):

Set gnus-large-newsgroup to 500.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Selecting-a-Group.html

> The *gnus-large-newsgroup* variable says what Gnus should consider to be a big group. If it is nil, no groups are considered big. The default value is 200. If the group has more (unread and/or ticked) articles than this, Gnus will query the user before entering the group. The user can then specify how many articles should be fetched from the server. If the user specifies a negative number (-n), the n oldest articles will be fetched. If it is positive, the n articles that have arrived most recently will be fetched

Comment: I looked at that variable already. It's value is 200. When I enter a group, the default value shown is the number of messages, not 200, so this will not solve it. I would like to set the default number of messages to fetch so that I can just press Enter when going into a group, rather than having to type "500" each time.

Comment: Could you add version info regarding your emacs, gnus and OS/distribution?  The variable works as documented for nntp select method in Debian/Testing emacs24.

Comment: gnus 5.13 in Emacs 24.5.1. That variable defaults to 200 for me. If I set it to 500, no change in behaviour is seen. When I select a group, I am prompted as to how many articles I would like to download, with the default value being the total number of articles in the group.

Comment: That variable seems to control the maximum number of articles, which will *trigger* the prompt to ask how many articles to download. I'm talking about changing the default value, which appears in the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a sorely missing feature.  Having to stop and choose a number and type it in every time you open a group with a large backlog is tiresome.

As a workaround, you could bind `RET` in the `*Group*` buffer to a function that runs:

```
(gnus-group-select-group number)
```

...where `number` is what you would normally type at the prompt.

However, note from the docstring:

```
If ALL is non-nil, already read articles become readable.
```

This means that using this workaround will always load already-read articles--which, for me, defeats the whole purpose.

I suppose another possible workaround would be to write a function which compares the number of unread articles in the group to the `gnus-large-newsgroup` variable, and if larger, calls `gnus-group-select-group`, inputs the number directly into the minibuffer, and presses `RET`.  Kind of an ugly hack, but I guess it would work.

The way gnus is installed on my system, the uncompiled elisp code isn't available, so modifying it will take a lot more effort.  However, once you have the gnus code handy, it would probably not be too difficult to add a new setting to gnus for a default number of articles to load...

Answer (score 1):

I hit exactly the same problem while using Gnus for the first time.  After browsing the source code for a while, I found the following line from `gnus-sum.el.gz` is the cause.

```el
(defun gnus-articles-to-read (group &optional read-all)
  "Find out what articles the user wants to read."
  (let* ((only-read-p t)
     (articles
      (gnus-list-range-difference
      ;; Select all articles if `read-all' is non-nil, or if there
      ;; are no unread articles.
           (if (or read-all ...)
               (or ...)
        ;; Select only the "normal" subset of articles.
        (setq only-read-p nil)
            ...))))
    ...
              (let* ((cursor-in-echo-area nil)
             (initial (gnus-parameter-large-newsgroup-initial
                   gnus-newsgroup-name))
             (default (if only-read-p
                      (or initial gnus-large-newsgroup)
                    number))
             (input
              (read-string
               (if only-read-p
                   (format
                "How many articles from %s (available %d, default %d): "
                (gnus-group-real-name
                 (gnus-group-decoded-name gnus-newsgroup-name))
                number default)
                 (format
                  "How many articles from %s (%d default): "
                  (gnus-group-real-name
                   (gnus-group-decoded-name gnus-newsgroup-name))
                  default))
                       ...
```

I comment out the following line.

```
        ;; (setq only-read-p nil)
```

And now it got the default 200 as in the following snapshot.

[image: snapshot showing up default 200]

I am on Emacs 25.3 with Gnus 5.13 under Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

---

## Follow-up

I tracked the source code repo and found the following.

```
commit 4c7468f6446a25c4abbbacf495d45e30103f26b7
Author: Lars Magne Ingebrigtsen <larsi@gnus.org>
Date:   Tue Mar 15 22:57:48 2011 +0000

    gnus-sum.el (gnus-articles-to-read): Revert back to old behaviour if we're selecting a group with unread articles.

diff --git a/lisp/gnus/ChangeLog b/lisp/gnus/ChangeLog
index 1b4cd18695..27fdc563db 100644
--- a/lisp/gnus/ChangeLog
+++ b/lisp/gnus/ChangeLog
@@ -1,5 +1,8 @@
 2011-03-15  Lars Magne Ingebrigtsen  <larsi@gnus.org>

+   * gnus-sum.el (gnus-articles-to-read): Revert back to old behaviour if
+   we're selecting a group with unread articles.
+
    * nnimap.el (nnimap-open-connection-1): Allow `network-only', too.

    * gssapi.el: New file separated out from imap.el to provide a general
diff --git a/lisp/gnus/gnus-sum.el b/lisp/gnus/gnus-sum.el
index 0fa1d5979c..385460378b 100644
--- a/lisp/gnus/gnus-sum.el
+++ b/lisp/gnus/gnus-sum.el
@@ -5798,7 +5798,8 @@ gnus-article-marked-p

 (defun gnus-articles-to-read (group &optional read-all)
   "Find out what articles the user wants to read."
-  (let* ((articles
+  (let* ((only-read-p t)
+    (articles
      ;; Select all articles if `read-all' is non-nil, or if there
      ;; are no unread articles.
      (if (or read-all
@@ -5822,6 +5823,7 @@ gnus-articles-to-read
         (gnus-uncompress-range (gnus-active group)))
           (gnus-cache-articles-in-group group))
        ;; Select only the "normal" subset of articles.
+       (setq only-read-p nil)
        (gnus-sorted-nunion
         (gnus-sorted-union gnus-newsgroup-dormant gnus-newsgroup-marked)
         gnus-newsgroup-unreads)))
@@ -5845,18 +5847,25 @@ gnus-articles-to-read
          (let* ((cursor-in-echo-area nil)
             (initial (gnus-parameter-large-newsgroup-initial
                   gnus-newsgroup-name))
+            (default (if only-read-p
+                     (or initial gnus-large-newsgroup)
+                   number))
             (input
              (read-string
-              (format
-               "How many articles from %s (available %d, default %d): "
-               (gnus-group-decoded-name
-                (gnus-group-real-name gnus-newsgroup-name))
-               number
-               (or initial gnus-large-newsgroup))
+              (if only-read-p
+                  (format
+                 "How many articles from %s (available %d, default %d): "
+                 (gnus-group-decoded-name
+                  (gnus-group-real-name gnus-newsgroup-name))
+                 number default)
+                (format
+               "How many articles from %s (%d available): "
+               (gnus-group-decoded-name
+                (gnus-group-real-name gnus-newsgroup-name))
+               default))
               nil
               nil
-              (number-to-string
-               (or initial gnus-large-newsgroup)))))
+              (number-to-string default))))
            (if (string-match "^[ \t]*$" input) number input)))
         ((and (> scored marked) (< scored number)
               (> (- scored number) 20))
```

So designed behavior is that if all messages under the group are read, then it will prompt with a default number, otherwise none is provided.

I believe the more proper way to solve the problem is not to modify the source code, but rather mark all messages in the group as read by hitting `c` on the group buffer.

I reverted my change on `gnus-sum.el.gz` and the following also works now.

[image: read group without new message]

But the other group still doesn't prompt a default.

[image: read group with new messages]